# Python Scaling loops

Tags: python, loops, scale

For each letter in the alphabet. The code should go to website.com/a and grab a table. Then it should check for a next button grab the link and makesoup and grab the next table and repeat until there is no valid next link. Then move to website.com/b(next letter in alphabet) and repeat. But I can only get as far as 2 pages for each letter. the first for loop grabs page 1 and the second grabs page 2 for each letter. I know I could write a loop for as many pages as needed but that is not scalable. How can I fix this?

```
from nfl_fun import make_soup
import urllib.request
import os
from string import ascii_lowercase
import requests

letter = ascii_lowercase
link = "https://www.nfl.com"

for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    soup = make_soup(f"https://www.nfl.com/players/active/{letter}")
    for tbody in soup.findAll("tbody"):
        for tr in tbody.findAll("a"):
            if tr.has_attr("href"):
                print(tr.attrs["href"])

for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    soup = make_soup(f"https://www.nfl.com/players/active/{letter}")
    for page in soup.footer.findAll("a", {"nfl-o-table-pagination__next"}):
        pagelink = ""
        footer = ""
        footer = page.attrs["href"]
        pagelink = f"{link}{footer}"        
        print(footer)
        getpage = requests.get(pagelink)                            
        if getpage.status_code == 200:
            next_soup = make_soup(pagelink)
            for next_page in next_soup.footer.findAll("a", {"nfl-o-table-pagination__next"}):
                print(getpage)
                for tbody in next_soup.findAll("tbody"):
                    for tr in tbody.findAll("a"):
                        if tr.has_attr("href"):
                            print(tr.attrs["href"])
                            soup = next_soup
```

Thank You again,

Comment: What exactly is the error? I understand your goal but am confused why it is breaking after the second letter. Can you post the full error contents please

Comment: No error it just doesnt grab page 3(or more) for any of the letters. It only grabs page 1 and 2 for each letter. Some letters have 1 page some have 2 some have 3 and so on.

Comment: Use something like a list, the idea is to have something that process item in the list, as you discover more items, put them into the list.  So as you discover new page, add that page to the list, and have the page processor or something that pop off a page and process it.  As it process the page any newly discover page will get add to the list.  This will remove a lot of those loops that you have.

Comment: @noobius Can you expand on this? I'm confused on exactly how a list would help here. It doesn't seem like the problem is due to the lack of iterating through the alphabet, but rather that a table is not discovered, hence the loop terminating. OP, which print statement is executed last in your output?

Comment: Thank you for your time the answer below works. If it still matters the last output was the first next link for w. /players/active/w?query=w&after=c2ltcGxlLWN1cnNvcjk5 and for noobius I did try list but it was the same thing my list would only iterate 2 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an element in there that says when the "Next" button is inactive. So that'll tell you you are on the last page. So what you can do is a while loop, and just keep going to the next page, until it reaches the last page (Ie "Next" is inactive) and then tell it to stop the loop and go to the next letter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import ascii_lowercase
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re

letters = ascii_lowercase
link = "https://www.nfl.com"

results = pd.DataFrame()
for letter in letters:
    continueToNextPage = True
    after = ''
    page=1
    while continueToNextPage == True:
        # Get the Table
        url = f"https://www.nfl.com/players/active/{letter}?query={letter}&after={after}"
        response = requests.get(url, 'html.parser')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        temp_df = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]    
        results = results.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True) 

        print ("{letter}: Page: {page}".format(letter=letter.upper(), page=page))

        # Check if next page is inactive
        buttons = soup.find('div', {'class':'nfl-o-table-pagination__buttons'})
        regex = re.compile('.*pagination__next.*is-inactive.*')
        if buttons.find('span', {'class':regex}):
            continueToNextPage = False
        else:
            after = buttons.find('a', {'title':'Next'})['href'].split('after=')[-1]
            page+=1
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
                  Player          Current Team Position Status
0         Chidobe Awuzie        Dallas Cowboys       CB    ACT
1             Josh Avery      Seattle Seahawks       DT    ACT
2           Genard Avery   Philadelphia Eagles       DE    ACT
3        Anthony Averett      Baltimore Ravens       CB    ACT
4              Lee Autry         Chicago Bears       DT    ACT
5           Denico Autry    Indianapolis Colts       DT    ACT
6           Tavon Austin        Dallas Cowboys       WR    UFA
7        Blessuan Austin         New York Jets       CB    ACT
8         Antony Auclair  Tampa Bay Buccaneers       TE    ACT
9      Jeremiah Attaochu        Denver Broncos       LB    ACT
10       Hunter Atkinson       Atlanta Falcons       OT    ACT
11           John Atkins         Detroit Lions       DE    ACT
12           Geno Atkins    Cincinnati Bengals       DT    ACT
13        Marcell Ateman     Las Vegas Raiders       WR    ACT
14          George Aston       New York Giants       RB    ACT
15    Dravon Askew-Henry       New York Giants       DB    ACT
16          Devin Asiasi  New England Patriots       TE    ACT
17    George Asafo-Adjei       New York Giants       OT    ACT
18             Ade Aruna     Las Vegas Raiders       DE    ACT
19       Grayland Arnold   Philadelphia Eagles      SAF    ACT
20            Dan Arnold     Arizona Cardinals       TE    ACT
21         Damon Arnette     Las Vegas Raiders       CB    UDF
22     Ray-Ray Armstrong        Dallas Cowboys       LB    UFA
23     Ka'John Armstrong        Denver Broncos       OT    ACT
24     Dorance Armstrong        Dallas Cowboys       DE    ACT
25     Cornell Armstrong        Houston Texans       CB    ACT
26       Terron Armstead    New Orleans Saints       OT    ACT
27      Ryquell Armstead  Jacksonville Jaguars       RB    ACT
28         Arik Armstead   San Francisco 49ers       DE    ACT
29            Alex Armah     Carolina Panthers       FB    ACT
                 ...                   ...      ...    ...
3180       Clive Walford        Miami Dolphins       TE    UFA
3181        Cameron Wake      Tennessee Titans       DE    UFA
3182     Corliss Waitman   Pittsburgh Steelers        P    ACT
3183         Rick Wagner     Green Bay Packers       OT    ACT
3184        Bobby Wagner      Seattle Seahawks      MLB    ACT
3185        Ahmad Wagner         Chicago Bears       WR    ACT
3186        Colby Wadman        Denver Broncos        P    ACT
3187      Christian Wade         Buffalo Bills       RB    ACT
3188     LaAdrian Waddle         Buffalo Bills       OT    UFA
3189      Oshane Ximines       New York Giants       LB    ACT
3190        Trevon Young      Cleveland Browns       DE    ACT
3191           Sam Young     Las Vegas Raiders       OT    ACT
3192         Kenny Young      Los Angeles Rams      ILB    ACT
3193         Chase Young   Washington Redskins       DE    UDF
3194        Bryson Young       Atlanta Falcons       DE    ACT
3195        Isaac Yiadom        Denver Broncos       CB    ACT
3196         T.J. Yeldon         Buffalo Bills       RB    ACT
3197         Deon Yelder    Kansas City Chiefs       TE    ACT
3198         Rock Ya-Sin    Indianapolis Colts       CB    ACT
3199     Eddie Yarbrough     Minnesota Vikings       DE    ACT
3200       Marshal Yanda      Baltimore Ravens       OG    ACT
3201         Tavon Young      Baltimore Ravens       CB    ACT
3202     Brandon Zylstra     Carolina Panthers       WR    ACT
3203       Jabari Zuniga         New York Jets       DE    UDF
3204       Greg Zuerlein        Dallas Cowboys        K    ACT
3205        Isaiah Zuber  New England Patriots       WR    ACT
3206       Justin Zimmer      Cleveland Browns       DT    ACT
3207      Anthony Zettel     Minnesota Vikings       DE    ACT
3208       Kevin Zeitler       New York Giants       OG    ACT
3209   Olamide Zaccheaus       Atlanta Falcons       WR    ACT

[3210 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the effort here. It does work. I had tried several variations with while loops and couldn't get it. but this is it.

Comment: Ya I'm still trying to completely grasp the while loop concepts. Not entirely sure I'm doing it the "correct" way, but the way I sort of think of it is create a variable as sort of the "on/off" switch. You turn the switch "On" right before going into the loop, and then think about the situation for when you need to turn the switch "off". And make an if statement to check for that situation in the loop